# The application’s bundle identifier does not match its code signing identifier? Not Carthage based issue

Tags: ios, flutter, certificate, bundle, identifier

Has anyone had this issue and knows how to resolve it? I've had a ticket open with Apple Support for over a month and still don't have it resolved.

I cannot install my app on a physical device for testing or archive it for distribution. I keep receiving the error "the application’s bundle identifier does not match its code signing identifier." I don't know if it's the root cause but I can see in the developer site that my Team ID does not match what is on my development certificate or shown in Xcode.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the app, deleting and re-downloading provisioning profiles, revoking and recreating certificates, logging in/out, and I still get the same error.

I've also confirmed bundle IDs match between app store connect and xcode. This is only happening when trying to install to a local test device or archiving. I guess different certs are used for simulators. For more context, this app is developed in Flutter, and I have installed locally before but never published the Flutter version.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a resolution? I'm also facing this under similar circumstances